# Refreshing datatables.net table data in Angular 7 keeps a copy of the old data from table's first loading

Tags: angular, datatables, angular7, angular-datatables

I'm trying to make a live reporting from a REST API request using the datatables.net library in Angular 7. If I make a data update into the database, the data in the table is updated. However, If I touch the table (i.e. reorder, search for something, change the page, etc), on data reloading (which occurs every 5 seconds), in the table is added the data from the first load of the table. If I touch the table again, the updated data disappears, and only the old data remains, until the next data update, when the new data is added again in the table.

This is the state of the table when the page loads
[image: State of the table on page load]

This is the state of the table when the data in the database is updated

[image: state of the table when the data in the database is updated]

This is the behavior of the table when any change is made on the table (i.e. sort, search, switch page, etc)
[image: behavior of the table when any change is made on the table]

This is the code for the component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DownloadService } from '../services/download/download.service';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-downloads',
  templateUrl: './downloads.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./downloads.component.css']
})

export class DownloadsComponent implements OnInit {

  downloadData$: any[] = [];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  interval: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private data: DownloadService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      responsive: true
    };

    this.data.GetDownloads().subscribe(data => {
      this.downloadData$ = data;
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.refreshData();
    }, 5000);
  }

  refreshData() {
    this.data.GetDownloads().subscribe(data => {
      this.downloadData$ = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and this is the html file

```
<div>
  <table style="text-align: center;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
    datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Logger Name</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let download of downloadData$">
        <td>{{ download.logger.name }}</td>
        <td [attr.data-order]="download.progress"><progress [attr.value]="download.progress" max="100"></progress>
          {{ download.progress }}%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your html file

Comment: sure, i added it now

Answer (score 3):

You have to destroy the table first and re render. You can refer the article [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender).
A code snippet if link gets disabled in future.

```
rerender(): void {
this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
  // Destroy the table first
  dtInstance.destroy();
  // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
  this.dtTrigger.next();
});
}
```

Another solution is as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301764/angular-datatables-reload-data)

Let me know if this solution works or if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

I did a sample how it can work well when you try to do a **rerender** on *[angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)*. It works on Angular 9.
You must use ChangeDetectorRef because base class that provides change detection functionality. A change-detection tree collects all views that are to be checked for changes. Use the methods to add and remove views from the tree, initiate change-detection, and explicitly mark views as dirty, meaning that they have changed and need to be re-rendered.
Check it out: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

**stuff.html**

```
<table 
    datatable
    *ngIf="myData.length" 
    [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
    [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
    class="table table-bordered table-striped"
>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Stuff1 </th>
            <th> Stuff2 </th>
            <th> Stuff3 </th>
            <th> Stuff4 </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of myData">
            <td> {{ data.stuff1 }} </td>
            <td> {{ data.stuff2 }} </td>
            <td> {{ data.stuff3 }} </td>
            <td> {{ data.stuff4 }} °C </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**stuff.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-stuff',
    templateUrl: './stuff.component.html'
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective) datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

    public dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    public dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    constructor(
       private readonly chRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
       private readonly stuffService: StuffService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.stuffService.list().subscribe(response => {
            this.myData = response;
            //put this line before call dtTrigger
            this.chRef.detectChanges();
            this.dtTrigger.next();
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    }

    public rerender() {
        this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
            dtInstance.destroy();

            this.stuffService.list().subscribe(response => {
                this.myData = response;
                this.dtTrigger.next();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and this behavior is very weird, it defaults back to the original values. This is not a problem with your code but instead with angular-datatable library.

For the meantime downgrade to angular-datatables@6.0.0 using

`npm install --save angular-datatables@6.0.0`
or
`yarn add angular-datatables@6.0.0`

I tried it out and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: hmm if that doesn't work, can you try destroying the datable instance and rerendering it again? https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

Comment: I've also tried the solution from here: https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1146. Unfortunately nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Calling the dtTrigger after a callback from my data update method solved it:

```
rerender(): void {
  this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => { 

    // Destroy the table first
    dtInstance.destroy();

    //reload your data
    this.reloadDataMethod(()=>{

       // Call the dtTrigger to rerender **after callback**
       this.dtTrigger.next();

    })
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your populate data function or once again rebind the data before calling dtTrigger.next() and after dtInstance.destroy()