# Real time reporting from REST API using datatables.net for Angular 7

Tags: angular, datatables, angular7, angular-datatables, real-time-updates

Is it possible to make a real time reporting using datatables.net library for a table in Angular 7 through a REST API? The idea would be to make an api request every 5 seconds and update the table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use rxjs to call API periodically and rerender your datables.net table each time you recieve data.

Your table markup:

```
    <table id="datatables" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--Headers here-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let tableItem of tableData">
                <!--Data columns here-->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Declarations in component:

```
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

dtTrigger: Subject<AppraisalGridItem[]> = new Subject<AppraisalGridItem[]>();

tableData: any[] = [];

//flag to indicate initial data assignment
isInitStage: boolean = true;
```

Service call subscription:

```
    interval(5000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.yourService.getData()))
        .subscribe(data => {

            this.tableData= data;

            if (this.isInitStage) {
                this.dtTrigger.next();
                this.isInitStage = false;
            }
            else {
                this.rerenderTable();
            }          
        });
```

Basically you need to use `interval` method to call API periodically, then you need to pipe through `switchMap` to flatten output and process only latest result. And finally for subsequent requests (after first init one) you will need to rerender your table by destroying it first:

```
rerenderTable(): void {
    this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.destroy();
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
}
```

You can avoid extra rerendering if you add any indicator (timestamp, checksum etc) that can tell if data was changed

Comment: Hi, the solution is not working. First, it throws: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` Then, it throws: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dtInstance' of undefined`. Then it has the same behavior as the problem described on this post: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847648/refreshing-datatables-net-table-data-in-angular-7-keeps-a-copy-of-the-old-data-f), but with the aforementioned errors.